# jquery.inputmask.bundle.js duplicando os caracteres pressionados

Tags: jquery, input-mask

Estou utilizando [inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) para mascara de `CEP 99999-999` e após o objeto ser clonado, há a duplicidade de caractere pressionado. Geralmente ocorre quando chega no separador (-). Ex. se eu for digitar um CEP 12345-678, o valor fica sendo 12345-566, após o separador, os valores são duplicado. Se eu apagar os caracteres e começar a digitar novamente, os valores saem 11223-344.

Basicamente o código que estou utilizando para duplicar o campo é:

```
$('#clonar').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.cep').clone(true).appendTo('#ceps').val('');
});
```

Fiz um [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4gjcb19L/1/) com o exemplo. Para executar o 'problema' basta digitar qualquer CEP, clicar em clonar, e depois digitar o CEP para ver a duplicidade.

Alguém poderia me auxiliar quanto a este quesito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aplique a máscara somente quanto o elemento receber o `focus`, e coloque `false` na opção do `clone()`, para que ele não duplique os eventos (aliás, deixa sem opção, porque `false` já é a opção default):

```
$(document).on('focus', '.cep', function(){
   $(this).inputmask('99999-999');
});
```

Veja exemplo:

```js
$(document).on('focus', '.cep', function(){
  $(this).inputmask('99999-999');
})
$('#clonar').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.cep').clone().appendTo('#ceps').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" val="" class="cep"/>
  <button id="clonar">
    Clonar
  </button>
</div>

<div id="ceps">

</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Sam, funcionou corretamente. Valeu